# How to get the current value and update the state (Object) of a Parent component in Children component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have this state in my Parent component

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    middleInitial: "",
    lastName: "",
    imageFile: "",
    extension: "",
    mobileNumber: "",
    email: "",
    agreement1: false,
    agreement2: false,
    agreement3: false,
  });
```

and I pass it into the `Child Component` as a props but having an issue changing the value of `agreement1` , `agreement2` and `agreement3` which is a Boolean

```
 setFormData({ ...formData, firstName: e.target.value })
```

This is the code in the `Child Component` to update the state into the `Parent Component` and it works perfectly fine. but when I try to update the Boolean I don't know how to access the previous boolean value before updating it.

I want to do something like this.

```
setBooleanValue((prevVal)=> !prevVal)
```

so every time I click on it . I toggle the value of the boolean

```
setFormData({...formData,agreement2: (prevVal) => !prevVal})
```

I try this but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: You need to get reference from previous state and update the required field, `setFormData((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, agreement2: !prev.agreement2 };
    });`  Check this example, https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-child-component-forked-prvu88

Comment: Thanks for the idea it's working fine now. But this is my approach but same concept to the one that you've said `setFormData({...formData,agreement2: !formData.agreement2})` I just get a reference value 1st in the `formData` props and then update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using the state update function as below:

`setFormData((prev) => ({...prev,agreement2: !prev.agreement2}))`

Comment: Thanks for the idea it's working fine now. But this is my approach but same concept to the one that you've said `setFormData({...formData,agreement2: !formData.agreement2})` I just get a reference value 1st in the `formData` props and then update it.

Comment: It works too, just in case to not get the stale value an updater function is being used